# GAE Chat Data Persistance in Memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, chat

I'm writing a chat feature (like the Faceboook.com one) for a Google App Engine site. I need a way to keep track of what users have new messages. I'm currently trying to use Memcache:

```
class Message():
    def __init__(self, from_user_key, message_text)
        self.from_user_key = from_user_key
        self.message_text = message_text

class NewMessages():
    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []
    def add_message(self, message):
        self.messages.append(message)
    def get_messages(self):
        return self.messages
    def messages_sent(self):
        self.messages = [] #Clear all messages

def ChatUserManager():
    def load(user_key):
        manager = memcache.get("chat_user_%s" % user_key)
        if manager is not None:
            return manager
        else:
            manager = ChatUserManager(user_key)
            memcache.set("chat_user_%s" % user_key, manager)
            return manager
    def save(self):
        memcache.set("chat_user_%s" % user_key, self)
    def __init__(self, user_key):
        self.online = True
        self.new_messages = NewMessages()
        self.new_data = False
        self.user_key = user_key
    def recieve_message(self, message):
        self.new_data = True
        self.new_messages.add_message(Message(from_user_key, message_text))
    def send_message(self,  message):
        to_manager = ChatUserManager.load(message.from_user_key)
        to_manager.recieve_message(message)
    def client_receive_success(self):
        self.new_data = False
        self.new_messages.messages_sent()
```

This chat is user to user, like Facebook or an IM session, not group chat.

Each user will poll a url with ajax to get new messages addressed to them every x seconds. The chat manager will be loaded on that page (ChatUserManager.load(user_key)) and new messages will be checked for. When they are sent the manager will be told that the messages have been sent (manager.client_receive_success()), and then saved back to memcache (manager.save()).

When a user sends a message in the javascript client, it will send an ajax request to a url. The url will load the client's UserChatManager and call .send_message(Message(to_user_key, message_string))).

I'm concerned about the practicality of this model. If everything is in memcache how will it be synchronized across different pages?

Is there a better way to do this?

I do admit that I'm not a python pro yet so the code might not be very pythonic, are there any best practices I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't so much about how to share data between "pages" but how will the usability of the service will be impacted by using `memcache`.

There are no guarantees associated with data persistence in memcache: one moment its there, the other it might not.

Comment: So would using memcache + datastore fallback (Check memcache; if not there: get from datastore and set memcache key) make this approach work?

I realize that memcache is transient but for a chat feature it shouldn't matter too much right? I only need the new message data in memcache at 5min max (I'll put the expiration in there too).

Comment: Depends on the "quality of service" you can live with: you can either play with probabilities and go with memcache all the way OR write to datastore & memcache using different strategies: e.g. accumulate a bunch of data in memcache and do scheduled "backups" in datastore etc.